# ModelForm Showing DropDown instead of New Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am using Modelforms And my model is like

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    RestaurantName = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
```

My forms.py is like

```
class RestaurantForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = '__all__'
```

On Admin side On user field It letting me add a new user by opening a new form in popup but In model form its giving just drop down of existing users. Can I use same functionality of admin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better solution, but I would add a `+ button` to the form, that redirects to a `add_user` view, like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'add_user' %}" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
```

and create the `add_user` function in your views.py that handles that form.

Comment: how to remove that dropdown?  why I should show other user about my database entries ?